# VB.NET The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Tags: .net, vb.net

I got this error:

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

when trying to save my data from application. I'm using VB.net and sql server 2008.

this is my code:

```
Public Function Insert(ByVal Code As String, ByVal Name As String, Optional ByVal trans As SqlTransaction = Nothing) As Boolean
    Dim iResult As Integer
    Dim arrColumn() As String = {"Code", "Name"}
    Dim arrValue() As Object = {Code, Name}

    oConn.Open()
    Dim SQLString As String = GenInsert("BNK", arrColumn, arrValue)

    Dim comm As New SqlCommand
    Try
        'iResult = SCommand.Execute(SQLString, oConn)
        If trans IsNot Nothing Then
            oConn = trans.Connection
            comm.Transaction = trans
        Else
            oConn.Open()
        End If
        comm.Connection = oConn
        comm.CommandText = SQLString
        iResult = comm.ExecuteNonQuery
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex 'the error is pointed here
    Finally
        If trans Is Nothing Then
            oConn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
```

am I missing or something here?

-thanks for your help

Comment: Couple of answers trying to address the specific problem, but my advice would be - stop keeping connection objects in long-lived variables (such as `oConn` here) - create a *new* connection within this method, open it, run your command, then dispose of it. Ideally, wrap it in a `using` statement. Having a "shared" connection object that multiple methods access is a recipe for disaster - if not now, then further down the line. I.e. it'll be a complete disaster if/when you want to make use of multiple threads.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is correct. Your connection object should be declared and instantiated locally in your method and closed and disposed off in your Finally block. The only exception is when you're passing in the connection via the Transaction parameter. In that case, the connection should be declared locally in the calling method where the final commit or rollback happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the connection twice. Please remove the first `oConn.Open()` line, just above the `SQLString` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If `oConn` state is closed then only open the connection.

Instead of `oConn.Open()` use `if (oConn.State==ConnectionState.Close) then oConn.Open()`